# Github засчитывает коммиты на панель только из ветки мастер?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-branch

Собственно, вопрос в том, что я создал вторую ветку, назовем ее `dev` в нее сделал коммит, но он не учитывается в профиле. Заходя в ветку коммит виден, видно что сделан был от моей учетной записи.
Что мне необходимо сделать, чтобы данный коммит учитывался в профиле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, прямо под графиком профиля есть справка по этой теме - [ссылка на справку](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile)
Во вторых, цитата оттуда:

> Commits
>
> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of
>   the following conditions:
>
> ```
> The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
>
> The commits were made:
>     In the repository's default branch (usually master)
>     In the gh-pages branch (for repositories with Project Pages sites)
> ```
>
> In addition, at least one of the following must be true:
>
> ```
> You are a collaborator on the repository or are a member of the organization that owns the repository.
> You have forked the repository.
> You have opened a pull request or issue in the repository.
> You have starred the repository.
> ```

Итого, коммит будет отображаться только после слияния в мастер ветку. Как вариант - сделать ветку dev основной (default).